# android constraintlayout, how to left align a textview but it should show ellipsis when it is too long

Tags: android-constraintlayout

Having a few view horizontally left aligned, but only the right most one is right align to the window.

| [a][b][c] ---------- [d] |

when [b] has a lot text it should show ellipsis

| [a][b bbb...][c] [d] |

made it work in portrait
[image]

but does not work in landscape, the [c] is not left aligned but aligned at right side

[a][b] ------------------------------[c][d],

How to make the [c] always left aligned, test code is attached below?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="56dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topline_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/content_logo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="wer we rwe r wer eee 888 eee 888 eee eee eee eee  888" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/content_logo"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/content_avatar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/unknown_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topline_title" />
    <!-- -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxWidth="220dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/content_user_id_verified"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topline_title"
        tools:text="test eee 888" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/content_user_id_verified"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/content_user_name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/content_user_name"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/content_user_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/content_user_name"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_btn_play"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_user_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/content_user_name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/content_user_id_verified"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/content_message_time"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/content_user_name"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        tools:text="eee888 qwerqwe rqw er q we rq weerw erwe" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_message_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/content_user_id"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/content_user_id"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/content_logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/content_user_id"

        tools:text="30 Nov 2018" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/content_user_name"

        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat." />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up start/end and left/right in your horizontal chain.

For `id/content_message_time` change:

`app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/content_logo"`

to

`app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/content_logo"`

As a side note, `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` is deprecated. For your `id/content_user_id` it's recommended that you change:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

which should produce the same behavior.

Comment: @thanks @PawelLaskowski! did not noticed the EndOf cannt. be used with LeftOf.  by the way, isnt the `android:layout_width="0dp"` the way to say go with the constraint?

Comment: Yes, 0dp means 'match constraints' but it will stretch the View to take all available space between those constraints.